# value from getServerSideProps not updating until Nextjs server restart

Tags: graphql, next.js

I thought with getServerSideProps,data will updating whenever page is reload.But in this case , it doesn't.

In my case, if admin enter this page, it will display a button to edit product.

```
const productDetail: NextPage<Props> = ({ product }) => {
  //if admin enter this page
   <AdminCreateOrEditPrice product={product}/>

  //if user enter this page
  //display product's data
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ query }) => {
  const { data, error, loading } = await client.query<GetProductQuery>({
    query: GetProductDocument,
    variables: { productId: query.productId },
  });
  return {
    props: {
      product: data.getProduct.product,
    },
  };
};
```

EditProductData component have a mutation to edit product data.

```
const AdminCreateOrEditPrice= ({product}) =>{
 const [adminCreateOrEditPrice] = useAdminCreateOrEditPrice();

 const res = await adminCreateOrEditPrice({
        variables: {
          ...
        },
      });
      if (res.data?)
        alert(JSON.stringify(res.data));
   }
 return(
   <>
    //...
   </>
)
}
```

data was update in database, i can see it through alert(),but not at client although I reload page,until I restart Nextjs server,then it update.
What is error in my case and how can it fix it?

Edit:
I use codegen to generate hook

```
 @Mutation((_return) => PriceResponse)
  @UseMiddleware(checkAdmin)
  async adminCreateOrEditPrice(
    @Arg("priceInput") priceInput: PriceInput,
    @Arg("priceId") priceId: number,
    @Arg("productId") productId: number
  ): Promise<PriceResponse> {
    return await dataSource.transaction(async (transactionEntityManager) => {
      const productExisting = await transactionEntityManager.findOne(Product, {
        where: {
          id: productId,
        },
      });
      if (!productExisting)
        return {
          code: 400,
          success: false,
          message: "Product not found",
        };
      const priceExisting = await transactionEntityManager.findOne(Price, {
        where: {
          id: priceId,
        },
      });
      if (priceExisting) {
        if (productExisting.priceToDisplay === priceExisting.price) {
          productExisting.priceToDisplay = priceInput.price;
          await transactionEntityManager.save(productExisting);
        }

        (priceExisting.type = priceInput.type),
          (priceExisting.status = priceInput.status),
          (priceExisting.price = priceInput.price);
        await transactionEntityManager.save(priceExisting);

        return {
          code: 200,
          success: true,
          message: "Edit price successfully!",
          price: priceExisting,
        };
      } else {
        const newPrice = Price.create({
          type: priceInput.type,
          status: priceInput.status,
          price: priceInput.price,
          product: productExisting,
        });
        await transactionEntityManager.save(newPrice);
        return {
          code: 200,
          success: true,
          message: "Create new price successfully!",
          price: newPrice,
        };
      }
    });
  }
```

And this is schema to codegen gerenated.

```
mutation AdminCreateOrEditPrice($priceInput:PriceInput!,$priceId:Float!,$productId:Float!){
    adminCreateOrEditPrice(priceInput:$priceInput,priceId:$priceId,productId:$productId){
        code
        success
        message
        price{
            id
            type
            status
            price
        }
    }
}
```

It work well, i can get value return from server.

Comment: If you reload the page, your data should be updated too. If you look for a client-side update, you need set states for `product`

Comment: @NickVu i tried, but it not work, I logged incoming props in cache memory , it still return previous value.

Comment: you can try to put `console.log(data)` after `client.query` in `getServerSideProps` to see which data you have in the response. If it shows previous data, it means you have problems with `client.query`, not with `getServerSideProps`

Comment: Oh it shows previous data, so can you help me about error type I am facing?

Comment: Could you share `useAdminProductData` hook code?

Comment: of course, i just edited my question, can you check for me?

Comment: Hmm your code seems good to me, could you delete `.next` folder in your codebase and restart your server? Perhaps it has cached your data

Comment: @NickVu i tried, but the error still no disappear , do you have another way?

Answer (score 1):

i just found the way to fix my problem, I put this code at InMemoryCache of ApolloClient

```
 getProduct: {
            keyArgs: false,
            merge(existing, incoming) {
              console.log(incoming)
              return incoming.product;
            },
          },
```

i thought just getStaticProps need this code, but i'm wrong.
If you facing the problem like me,let try my way.